# Paraphrasing Prometheus Bound (Greek)

Tags: greek

In [Aeschylus' Prometheus Bound](http://www.theoi.com/Text/AeschylusPrometheus.html) I want to paraphrase these lines **in Greek**:

> PROMETHEUS [152] Oh if only he had hurled me below the earth, yes beneath Hades, the entertainer of the dead, into impassable Tartarus, and had ruthlessly fastened me in fetters no hand can loose, so that neither god nor any other might have gloated over this agony I feel! But, now, a miserable plaything of the winds, I suffer pains to delight my enemies.

Into:

> Oh if only he had hurled me below the earth, so that neither god nor any other might have gloated over this agony I feel! But, now, a miserable plaything of the winds, I suffer pains to delight my enemies.

I **think** [these](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text.jsp?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0009%3Acard%3D152) are the lines in Greek:

Προμηθεύς: εἰ γάρ μ᾽ ὑπὸ γῆν νέρθεν θ᾽ Ἅιδου 
τοῦ νεκροδέγμονος εἰς ἀπέρατον 
Τάρταρον ἧκεν, 
155δεσμοῖς ἀλύτοις ἀγρίως πελάσας, 
ὡς μήτε θεὸς μήτε τις ἄλλος 
τοῖσδ᾽ ἐπεγήθει. 
νῦν δ᾽ αἰθέριον κίνυγμ᾽ ὁ τάλας 
ἐχθροῖς ἐπίχαρτα πέπονθα.

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

delete from νέρθεν through Τάρταρον, and from δεσμοῖς through πελάσας. In other words, the paraphrase will be:

> εἰ γάρ μ᾽ ὑπὸ γῆν ... ἧκεν,
>   ... ὡς μήτε θεὸς μήτε τις ἄλλος
>   τοῖσδ᾽ ἐπεγήθει. νῦν δ᾽ αἰθέριον κίνυγμ᾽ ὁ τάλας
>   ἐχθροῖς ἐπίχαρτα πέπονθα.

Comment: I need to get rid of the "...". Without the "..." is it still grammatically correct? "εἰ γάρ μ᾽ ὑπὸ γῆν ἧκεν, ὡς μήτε θεὸς μήτε τις ἄλλος
τοῖσδ᾽ ἐπεγήθει. νῦν δ᾽ αἰθέριον κίνυγμ᾽ ὁ τάλας
ἐχθροῖς ἐπίχαρτα πέπονθα."

Comment: @Johan88, Yes, it's correct without them.

Comment: Dear @cnread I'm Alex, working at a Hong Kong Art and Design company. We're looking to build out own group of avid language enthusiasts to advise us. You are quite the knowledgeable, kind and helpful linguist, and I would like to ask if you'd like to join as a private adviser. We envisage an informal, unpaid advisory board (like StackExchange), except we can give credit on our (as of yet unmade) website, rather then Stack points. But if anyone can recommend a suitable payment system we're all ears. If you have any interest please let me know. All the very best, A. J. T. Whiteheart

Comment: Or, if you wood not be interested, please let me know here in the comments, thanks